# Error while initializing GVim

Tags: linux, vim, gvim

I'm using gVim on the Ubuntu 9.10 and using a [plugin](http://github.com/akitaonrails/vimfiles) to improve it. Since the installation of the plugin I can't open gVim through clicks on its icon. So I go to the Terminal and type gvim.

Before gVim opens, the following error is sent:

```
rodrigo3n@ubuntu:~$ gvim

E558: Terminal entry not found in terminfo
'gnome-256color' not known. Available builtin terminals are:
    builtin_gui
    builtin_riscos
    builtin_amiga
    builtin_beos-ansi
    builtin_ansi
    builtin_pcansi
    builtin_win32
    builtin_vt320
    builtin_vt52
    builtin_xterm
    builtin_iris-ansi
    builtin_debug
    builtin_dumb
defaulting to 'ansi'

Error detected while processing /home/rodrigo3n/.vimrc:
line  261:
E484: Can't open file $HOMEPATHvimfilessnippetssupport_functions.vim
Taglist: Exuberant ctags (http://ctags.sf.net) not found in PATH. Plugin is not
loaded.

** (gvim:3053): CRITICAL **: gtk_form_set_static_gravity: assertion `static_gravity_supported' failed

** (gvim:3053): CRITICAL **: gtk_form_set_static_gravity: assertion `static_gravity_supported' failed

** (gvim:3053): CRITICAL **: gtk_form_set_static_gravity: assertion `static_gravity_supported' failed

** (gvim:3053): CRITICAL **: gtk_form_set_static_gravity: assertion `static_gravity_supported' failed

** (gvim:3053): CRITICAL **: gtk_form_set_static_gravity: assertion `static_gravity_supported' failed
rodrigo3n@ubuntu:~$
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 5):

I have been seeing the same GTK criticals as well on my 9.10 installation with gVim. This is supposedly fixed by [patch 7.2.257](ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/patches/7.2/7.2.257). Ubuntu 9.10 is providing Vim 7.2.245, so we will see the warnings on Ubuntu until they update their vim package to at least 7.2.257. It doesn't seem to have any influence on the functionality of gVim though.

Also, it seems you need to install exuberant ctags:

```
sudo apt-get install exuberant-ctags
```

Finally, line 261 in your .vimrc is pointing to a non-existing file. Maybe the environment variable $HOMEPATH is not set?

Comment: and maybe he needs his TERM variable to be something different than 'gnome-256color' ... everything else in your answer is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could just add some entries to your .bashrc:

```
alias gvim="gvim -reverse 2>/dev/null"
alias tvim="gvim --servername localhost --remote-silent-tab 2>/dev/null"
```

This should be sufficient unless you're interested particularly in errors that gvim outputs.

Answer (score 1):

You can install "ncurses-term" for the error to really go away.

```
apt-get install ncurses-term
```

Thanks to [Matts blog](http://mattbriggs.net/posts/4c98a213696b640db4000004).